# Window functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following table:

```
id username
1   Jack
2   Will
3   Grace
4   Niv
```

I want to write a 3 column query which shows username, username before and username after based on dictionary order.

Meaning:

```
before username  after
       Grace     Jack
Grace  Jack      Niv
Jack   Niv       Will
Nive   Will
```

I wrote this query:

```
select lag(username,1) over (partition by username order by username ) as before,
    username,
    lead(username,1) over (partition by username order by username ) as after
from users
order by username
```

But it doesnt work. It shows me data only in the username column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT
    LAG(username, 1) OVER (ORDER BY username) AS before,
    username,
    LEAD(username, 1) OVER (ORDER BY username) AS after
FROM users
ORDER BY username;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1db77252545111f70b517addd3289e70)**

If you have duplicates in`users(username)` you could add `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT username FROM users) AS sub
ORDER BY ...;
```

**EDIT:**

> But it doesnt work. It shows me data only in the username column. What am I doing wrong?

When you use partition by you basically divide the rows into groups that share the same values of the `PARTITION BY` expression. So your window contains only one value. That is the reason why you get NULL (there is no prior/next value).

**[DBFidde Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c3696eef4a494d43ed9f1b0aae3553c1)**

**[DBFiddle Demo3 with duplicates per window](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3701aadd589a7697d0a3b9906bf0c96c)**

Answer (score 0):

another way without using window functions

> ```
> select a.username, 
>                   (select min(username) from users b
>                     where b.username > a.username) as after,
>                    (select max(username) from users c
>                    where c.username < a.username) as before
>  from users a
> order by username;
> ```